# Custom tabbar like container view with transparencies does not set the bottom layout guide

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, uikit

I want to create a **custom container view controller** that is pretty similar in behavior to a **translucent tabbar**. In my storyboard, I have something like this:

[image: Storyboard with container view[1]]

## The Problem

The content in the container view **expands under the tabbar button view** for the translucency. However, because this is not a standard tabbar `UIKit` is not setting up the `bottomLayoutGuide` in the child controller, which is by default `0`.

The result is that **the internal child controller does not properly set the insets on the content** when there is a scroll view, and therefore the last few pixels of the **content is covered** by the tababar view.

## Dirty solution

I am aware I could make a custom solution where I change the `contentInset` manually in the child view controllers, but this will be pretty cumbersome as there are multiple childs. Besides, this custom tabbar will animate in/out and can potentially have different sizes, so this approach will be very complex and ties very closely the child controllers to the custom tabbar implementation. **A lot of extra code and dependencies from child to tabbar layout!**

## What I want to achieve

If I would use a standard tabbar, the content would be displayed properly because the system uses the `bottomLayoutGuide` to add insets to the internal scrolls out of the box.

I want to somehow perform the same actions with my custom tab bar, so there is no need to change anything else in my child controllers code (and make them less dependent on the internals of the tab bar) and so I can reference the layout margins from InterfaceBuilder normally, no matter which is the container view.

As an extra benefit, this approach could allow me to change the `bottomLayoutGuide` when animating in/out or changing the tabbar size, and just ask the subviews to layout again.

## What I have tried

I have tried different actions on the `bottomLayoutGuide` of both the tabBar and child controllers. Some examples I have tried are:

`bottomLayoutGuide.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(40)`
`bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(tabBarView.topAnchor)`

And I have also tried to call `view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` just in case, but no matter what I do `bottomLayoutGuide.length` always seems to return `0.0`.

I have also seen that the views now have a `layoutMarginsGuide` but it does not seem to be the same thing.

## Questions

- **Why is the `bottomLayoutGuide` always 0**? Am I missing something here?
- Does anyone know how to solve this in an elegant way? **Any other clean approach** to the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution?